# jQuery snippet to swap two sets of elements with animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, swap

is there some jQuery code to swap 2 sets of elements with animation?

i only found
[Move list item to top of unordered list using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625960/move-list-item-to-top-of-unordered-list-using-jquery/5984886) but its too limited (only slide element to top and not accounting for different margins).

Comment: oops, meant to answer my own question, but thats not really possible as a new user. anyway, heres the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/ZXYZ3/139/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or even better yet, use [Quicksand](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/)

Answer (score 6):

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZXYZ3/139). arbitrary borders, margins, paddings, sizes etc. supported and still no jumps at animation end.

```
function slideSwap($set1, $set2) {

//$elem.append(infoString($elem));
//$after.append(infoString($after));
$set1.css("color", "red");
$set2.css("color", "blue");    
var $set3 = $set2.last().nextAll();
$set3.css("color", "green");

var mb_prev = cssprop($set1.first().prev(), "margin-bottom");
if (isNaN(mb_prev)) mb_prev = 0;
var mt_next = cssprop($set2.last().next(), "margin-top");
if (isNaN(mt_next)) mt_next = 0;

var mt_1 = cssprop($set1.first(), "margin-top");
var mb_1 = cssprop($set1.last(), "margin-bottom");
var mt_2 = cssprop($set2.first(), "margin-top");
var mb_2 = cssprop($set2.last(), "margin-bottom");

var h1 = $set1.last().offset().top + $set1.last().outerHeight() - $set1.first().offset().top;
var h2 = $set2.last().offset().top + $set2.last().outerHeight() - $set2.first().offset().top;

move1 = h2 + Math.max(mb_2, mt_1) + Math.max(mb_prev, mt_2) - Math.max(mb_prev, mt_1);
move2 = -h1 - Math.max(mb_1, mt_2) - Math.max(mb_prev, mt_1) + Math.max(mb_prev, mt_2);
move3 = move1 + $set1.first().offset().top + h1 - $set2.first().offset().top - h2 + 
    Math.max(mb_1,mt_next) - Math.max(mb_2,mt_next);

// let's move stuff
$set1.css('position', 'relative');
$set2.css('position', 'relative');
$set3.css('position', 'relative');    
$set1.animate({'top': move1}, {duration: 1000});
$set3.animate({'top': move3}, {duration: 500});
$set2.animate({'top': move2}, {duration: 1000, complete: function() {
        // rearrange the DOM and restore positioning when we're done moving          
        $set1.insertAfter($set2.last())
        $set1.css({'position': 'static', 'top': 0});
        $set2.css({'position': 'static', 'top': 0});
        $set3.css({'position': 'static', 'top': 0});
    }
});


}
```

Comment: this is some interesting code.  I am trying to do my own sort using this as a basis.  Any comments/notes you could add to the fiddle would be invaluable.

Answer (score 1):

There's a jQuery plugin to do it now, I haven't tried it yet, but the demo seems to work nicely: http://biostall.com/swap-and-re-order-divs-smoothly-using-jquery-swapsie-plugin

Comment: This is really helpful

Answer (score -1):

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/26UNk/

```
$("#content ul").sortable({
    opacity: 0.6,
    cursor: 'move',
    update: function() {
        var order = $(this).sortable("serialize") + '&action=updateRecordsListings';
        $.post("updateDB.php", order, function(theResponse) {
            $("#response").html(theResponse);
        });
    }
});
```

That might help (it does have a dragging element to it)