# how to give an animation effect when <li> moves to top or bottom

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

how to give an animation effect when li moves to top or bottom.

please check my [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/kannankds/4s2433x2/1/) , here I'am trying to add an animation effect when `li` moves bottom or top on click event.

**index.html**:

```
<ul class="kds">
<li>tile dtls1</li>
<li>tile dtls2</li>
<li>tile dtls3</li>
<li>tile dtls4</li>
<li>tile dtls5</li>
<li>tile dtls6</li>
</ul>
```

**script.js**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.previous').click(function() {
    var current = $('.currentSelection');
    current.prev().before(current);

  });
  $('.next').click(function() {
    var current = $('.currentSelection');
    current.next().after(current);
  });
  $(".kds li").on("click", function() {
    $(".kds li").removeClass("currentSelection");
    $(this).addClass("currentSelection");

  });

});
```

**style.css**

```css
.kds {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.kds li {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 1px;
}

.currentSelection {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery snippet to swap two sets of elements with animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984928/jquery-snippet-to-swap-two-sets-of-elements-with-animation)

Comment: If you position these elements absolute, you could give the elements a CSS transition.

Comment: can you update my fiddle

Comment: No. Just look at the answers of the provided link or google ``css transitions``.

Comment: what type of animation you are looking for ?

Comment: @ Jinu Kurian  just a moving effect, now in my fiddle its jumping , iam trying a moving effect that the user needs to feel that its changing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created an animation with `li` move up and down.

Please try:

**UPDATE**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.previous').click(function() {
    var current = $('.currentSelection');
    if( current.index() != 0 && !current.is(":animated") ){
      currentTop = parseInt(current.css("top").replace("px",""));
      current.animate({top:currentTop - 33 })
      current.prev().animate({top:currentTop + 33},function(){
          current.css("top",0).prev().css("top",0);
          current.prev().before(current);
      })
    }
  });
  
  $('.next').click(function() {
    var current = $('.currentSelection');
    if( current.index() != ( $(".kds li").length-1)  && !current.is(":animated") ){
      currentTop = parseInt(current.css("top").replace("px",""));
      current.animate({top:currentTop + 33 })
      current.next().animate({top:currentTop - 33},function(){
          current.css("top",0).next().css("top",0);
          current.next().after(current);
      })
    }
  });
  
  $(".kds li").on("click", function() {
    $(this).css("top","0px");
    $(".kds li").removeClass("currentSelection");
    $(this).addClass("currentSelection");
  });

});
```

```css
.kds {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.kds li {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 1px;
  position:relative;
  height:20px;
}

.currentSelection {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="kds">
  <li>tile dtls1</li>
  <li>tile dtls2</li>
  <li>tile dtls3</li>
  <li>tile dtls4</li>
  <li>tile dtls5</li>
  <li>tile dtls6</li>
</ul>
<input type="button" value="previous" class="previous">
<input type="button" value="next" class="next">
```

or JSFiddle : https://fiddle.jshell.net/e1jgusc1/1/

Comment: @P.Frank Please check your sample. Your code will not work for the first click on every `li` element, until the `li` has assigned with `.css("top","0px");`. So add this line `$(this).css("top","0px");` in the `$(".kds li")` click event.

Comment: @JohnR Thanks. With firefox working good but effectively in Chrome dont work. I have updated my answer and now work for all browser.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code snippets for your `current` element on both previous and next click event to achieve animation effect, just add the follwing line `current.hide().fadeIn("slow");`

**script.js**:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.previous').click(function() {
    var current = $('.currentSelection');
    current.prev().before(current); 
    current.hide().fadeIn("slow");

  });
  $('.next').click(function() {
    var current = $('.currentSelection');
    current.next().after(current);
    current.hide().fadeIn("slow");
  });
  $(".kds li").on("click", function() {
    $(".kds li").removeClass("currentSelection");
    $(this).addClass("currentSelection");

  });

});
```

[**DEMO**](https://fiddle.jshell.net/4s2433x2/4/)

Comment: multiple click it makes problem

Comment: Then you should wrap your `ul` under some `div` with fixed height.