# How do I change list items postion in list when clicked to being the top list item

Tags: css, list, html, position

This is for thumbnails that will animate to the top left of my list and then open up to larger images

this is the structure, its a large list I just want to know the best method to position these items, or should i be doing them as divs instead of list items?

```
<li  class="thumb">
    <img src="img/work/thumbemphasis.jpg">
        <div class="thumb-caption">
            <h4>Creative</h4>
        </div>
</li>
......
<li class="thumb">
<img src="img/work/thumbscale.jpg">
    <div class="thumb-caption">
        <h4>Creative</h4>
    </div>
</li>
```

ill apply this to the items which animates the size change using css, i just need to move it to the top of the list now... but am unsure how to go about it, any help would be appreciated thanks,

```
 $(".thumb").click(function(){
         this.style.width="850px";
         this.style.height="600px";
   });
```

thanks

Comment: One "hack" way I can think of - have the event handler remove the item from the `ul`, then prepend itself to the `ul` so that it appears at the top. I don't know how you could animate that, however.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisHayes that sounds like a good way, may have to go with that if I cant use animate

Comment: @JCrump Don't worry... Upvoted!

Comment: check out this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625960/move-list-item-to-top-of-unordered-list-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you like to have the first image large and the others as thumbnails. When a thumbnail is clicked it takes the position of the first image. The previous large image goes back in the list.

My suggestion:

Let the first list item be the placeholder for what ever list iten is clicked and add a class that moves the active list item over the placeholder by absolute positioning. All other list items can float around.
css:

```
.thumb {
 float: left;
 }
.thumb.active {
position: absolute; 
top:0; 
left:0;
width:600px;
height: 850px;}

.placeholder {
width:600px;
height: 850px;}
```

html

```
<ul>
<li class='placeholder'></il>
<li class='thumb'>...</li>
...
<li class='thumb active'>...</li>
...
</ul>
```

javascript:

```
$(".thumb").click(function(){
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
     this.addClass('active');
```

});

I know this question is pretty old. But this is one of my first answers so please consider the check mark.