# Reoder menu link on Js

Tags: javascript, menu, responsive-design

I'm actually working on a responsive site. I'ld like to know if it's possible to re-order a menu-link ONLY when we are in a smartphone device using JS?  For example, Item 3 became item 1. I don't want to make a other nav block just for that.

Example:

- Item 1 (Item 1.1 - Item 1.2 - Item 1.3)
- Item 2 (Item 2.1 - Item 2.2 - Item 2.3)
- Item 3
- Item 4
- Item 5

---

Script:

```
function ReoderMenu() {
    var size = $(window).width();

    if (size < 479) {
    //Reoder it (item 3 -> Item 1)
    }
    else if (size >=1024) {
    //tablette device
    }
    else {
    //do something
    }
}
```

Thx in advance.

Comment: Yes it is definitely possible. And your code seems to be doing just that. What problems are you having? Are you also questioning 'how to swap Item 3 with Item 1'?

Comment: Yes, i want to swap Item 3 to Item 1 definitly.

Answer (score 0):

I've find a creepy solution :

HTML :

```
        <ul id="list">
             <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
             <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
             <li id="Item3"><a>Item 3</a></li>    
             <li><a>Item 4</a></li>
             <li><a>Item 5</a></li>
        </ul>
```

JS :

```
  $("#list li a").click(function() {        
       var before = "<nav id='#new'><ul><li><a>";
       var after  = "</a></li><li><a>Item1</a></li><li><a>Item2</a></li><li><a>Item4</a></li><li><a>Item5</a></li></ul></nav>";
       $("#list li").parent().before(before+"Item3"+after);
       $("#list").css("display","none");
     });
```

I hope someone had a better solution ?

**EDIT : I've find a better solution : $('#Item1').parent().prepend($('#Item3'));**

And I hardly recommand this topic : [Move list item to top of unordered list using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625960/move-list-item-to-top-of-unordered-list-using-jquery)