# Need to re-order an un-ordered list by time of day

Tags: javascript, timer

I have an un-ordered list that has 24 list items. I need to re-order them based on the hour of the day. For example: list item #16 needs to appear as list item #1 at 4pm. Any thoughts?

```
<ul id="foo2">
    <li>12am</li>
    <li>1am</li>
    <li>2am</li>
    <li>3am</li>
    <li>4am</li>
    <li>5am</li>
    <li>6am</li>
    <li>7am</li>
    <li>8am</li>
    <li>9am</li>
    <li>10am</li>
    <li>11am</li>
    <li>12pm</li>
    <li>1pm</li>
    <li>2pm</li>
    <li>3pm</li>
    <li>4pm</li>
    <li>5pm</li>
    <li>6pm</li>
    <li>7pm</li>
    <li>8pm</li>
    <li>9pm</li>
    <li>10pm</li>
    <li>11pm</li>
</ul>
```

At 4pm i want the 4pm li to appear as if it is the first in the list. I have a slider attached to this list that shows 4 at a time, and want to start with the current hour.

Here is the working list/schedule (still in progress)
http://livestreamchicago.tv/content/lsctv#overlay-context=calendar-created/week/2013-W40

Comment: Please show us the markup of the list, and what you have tried to accomplish your task.

Comment: the current order wont change using a sort... :)

Comment: They are all `<li>3</li>` how would sorting them make a difference?

Comment: What's with the 3s? Is that supposed to be your list? If so, like Johan said, not only will you not notice any change to the list, there is no associated time or date meta data.

Comment: @Teeg: I don't think he wants metadata, he wants the first li to be at the top from 0:00 to 1:00, then the second one from 1:00 to 2:00 and so on (if I have understood "*item #16 needs to appear as item #1 at 4 pm*" correctly).

Comment: I was editing the example when you all viewed it. it is now ordered properly

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks. Still, please show us what javascript you have tried or where exactly you are stuck at creating one.

Comment: I have not found anything that is close to what i need, and im very new to Javascript, so im just stuck at this point

Comment: @Bergi Ah ok that makes sense. @Daniel, I suppose one way you can do it is sort the list normally first, then grab the nth `li` element based on the current time and move it to the first child position. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1626003/877472) might be helpful for the latter.

Comment: @Teeg it looks like the code you linked to is using .click to re-order. I need it to re-order without having to click on something. (page refresh is fine). Let me know if i am missing something from what you pointed me to.

Comment: @MattPatenaude we want the user to see what is happening at the current time, so the list will have to be re-ordered. Check out the schedule example here: http://livestreamchicago.tv/content/lsctv#overlay-context=calendar-created/week/2013-W40

Comment: @Daniel Its the code in the onClick function I was referring to. I was referring to the fashion in which you can bring the nth `li` element to the top. This line from that answer specifically: `$(this).parent().before("#list a:first");` looks like one way you can bring the element to the top. Replace `this` with the selector for the desired element, or the element itself.

Comment: @Teeg Ah, gotcha! I'll mess around with it and see if it works.

Comment: Looks like im going to need a lot more than just moving one element to the top. I need to have all of the following hours move underneath it as well to keep the hours in succession. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @Daniel You should generate the list from scratch. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of sorting the list, I'd recommend that you generate the list starting from the current hour as shown below. I've also added [a working example on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/owUYOGI/2/edit?html,js,output).

```
// Sets the inner contents of an HTML element identified by `listId` to a list
// of the next 24 hours starting from the current hour
//
//  Example:
//
//    <ol id="hour-list"></ol>
//    <script>listHours('foo-list')</script>
//    <ol id="hour-list"><li>12am</li><li>...</li></ol>
function listHours(listId) {
  // Get the current hour from a new Date object
  var currentHour = (new Date()).getHours();
  // An array to store the list items we generate
  var hourList = [];
  // Iterate through 24 hours starting from the current hour and add the list
  // items to the hour list
  var i = 0;
  while(i < 24) {
    var h = (currentHour + i) % 24;
    hourList.push('<li>' + formatHour(h) + '</li>');
    i++;
  }
  // Combine the list items and add them to element targeted by `listId`
  document.getElementById(listId).innerHTML = hourList.join('');
}

// Formats an hour (0-23) to an AM/PM format.
//
// Examples:
//
//  formatHour(0)   // => '12am'
//  formatHour(1)   // => '1am'
//  formatHour(13)  // => '1pm'
//  formatHour(23)  // => '11pm'
function formatHour(hour) {
  var fmtHour;
  if (hour === 0) {
    fmtHour = 12;
  } else if (hour > 12) {
    fmtHour = hour - 12;
  } else {
    fmtHour = hour;
  }
  var ampm = hour < 12 ? 'am' : 'pm';
  return fmtHour + ampm;
}
```

Comment: this works great! The only thing i need to do different is to  not show the current time, but to show Text or HTML code during the current hour. Any help on adjusting that so i can customize the list?

Comment: to be more clear, i intend on placing php code within each list item that pulls information from a calendar we are using.

Comment: Given your use case, you should sort your list using PHP rather than JavaScript since your users may be in different time zones.