# Reorder a sortable dragable Jquery ui list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a sortable, dragable Jquery UI list

```
<ul id="list">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>

$( "#list" )
  .sortable({ handle: ".handle" })
  .selectable()
    .find( "li" )
      .addClass( "ui-corner-all" )
      .prepend( "<div class='handle'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s'></span></div>" );
```

[You can see it working here JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yf5fz7xc/)

What I can work out is, how to re-order the list automatically.

I want any element that is clicked - **not moved** - to immediately automatically jump to the top of the list.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code does something similar:

Source: [Move list item to top of unordered list using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625960/move-list-item-to-top-of-unordered-list-using-jquery)

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yf5fz7xc/1/

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').click(function() {
      // the clicked LI
      var clicked = $(this);

      // all the LIs above the clicked one
      var previousAll = clicked.prevAll();

      // only proceed if it's not already on top (no previous siblings)
      if(previousAll.length > 0) {
        // top LI
        var top = $(previousAll[previousAll.length - 1]);

        // immediately previous LI
        var previous = $(previousAll[0]);

        // how far up do we need to move the clicked LI?
        var moveUp = clicked.attr('offsetTop') - top.attr('offsetTop');

        // how far down do we need to move the previous siblings?
        var moveDown = (clicked.offset().top + clicked.outerHeight()) - (previous.offset().top + previous.outerHeight());

        // let's move stuff
        clicked.css('position', 'relative');
        previousAll.css('position', 'relative');
        clicked.animate({'top': -moveUp});
        previousAll.animate({'top': moveDown}, {complete: function() {
          // rearrange the DOM and restore positioning when we're done moving
          clicked.parent().prepend(clicked);
          clicked.css({'position': 'static', 'top': 0});
          previousAll.css({'position': 'static', 'top': 0}); 
        }});
      }
    });
  });
```