# jQuery selectable and move an element when selectable

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Does anybody know how to move an li element to top on event click when selected using jqueryui?

I have a feature that allows you to select an (li) element on click, and needs to be move to top of the list when selected in a click event, if there is an element on top selected the element needs to go under that. This is kind of hierarchy items that later will sort some information based on these elements. Right now they can be drag but that is not what I want.

I was thinking of holding all the elements in result array, selected, unselected elements, then loop trough result array and check if element is selected push into selected array otherwise push into unselected array elements, then join those two arrays to display the right order by overwriting the result array. Any other suggestions.

I do not know how to approach this by using the jquery sortable on click event.

```
$(function() {
$("ul").on('click', 'li', function (e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) {
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    } else {
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    }
}).sortable({
    connectWith: "ul",
    delay: 150,         
    })

});
```

```css
ul {
    border:1px solid Black;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top
}
li {
    background-color:Azure;
    border-bottom:1px dotted Gray
}
li.selected {
    background-color:GoldenRod
}
```

```html
<p>
   Click to select multiple items
</p>
<br />

<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/lydaeve/pen/VQNeoR

Comment: I understood that after clicking an list-item it should be selected. 
The user can now drag to the top of the list unless there is already a selected item at the top than the item can only be dragged in second place. Is this what you want?  For example sort-order let us assume we have four attributs: price, delivery-time, ram-size, battery-size. The user picks delivery-time first and moves it to the top. Now he slects ram-size and moves it to the top but i will be placed in second place becauser there is already delivery-time at the top.

Comment: If the item selected is in the bottom needs to go to top to create some kind of hierarchy for selecting items, then later the selected list-item will order or sort some kind of information based on the list. For example price and size will be the list-items which are selected then will sort price and size with angularjs method orderBy  in ascending or descending order.

Comment: Yes that is what I want but the user can not drag the element, needs to move automatically when the element is selected.

Comment: If i understood it correctly: list with attributes: a,b,c,d  if user clicks on / selects b first it goes to the top, if he then clicks on d it goes in second place. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625960/